# rails doesn't know about "application/vnd.api+json" (ActionController::UnknownFormat)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, mime-types, jsonapi-resources

How to I solve this error I get in rails development.log:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat (PostsController#index is missing a template for this request format and variant.

request.formats: ["application/vnd.api+json"]
request.variant: []):
```

What I'm doing

I'm trying out the jsonapi resources gem with rails 5.1 with curl.
There's a demo app https://github.com/cerebris/peeps for reference.

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/vnd.api+json" -H 'Content-Type:application/vnd.api+json' 'http://localhost:3000/posts?user_email=example@example.net&user_token=ZuqysdFsH5pfhAUTDpe3'
```

Comment: were you able to solve that, facing a similar issue?

Comment: its been so long I actually forgot how I solved it, nowadays I use rails 6-0-stable maybe that's what you need.

Comment: the problem is I can't jump to 6-0-stable, it's a big application and upgrading will create different problems, I am currently on 4.1.15

Comment: I'm guessing the answer by murb written below didn't work

Comment: Exactly, that wasn't of much help.

Comment: send access to my GitHub id

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to register the mime type ("application/vnd.api+json") here: https://github.com/cerebris/peeps/blob/master/config/initializers/mime_types.rb

Note that the [correct mimetype for json is "application/json"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type#477819), changing your curl command to using the standard mime type might even work out of the box.